# Botones no funcionan en Modal bootstrap

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-4, modal

El Modal me abre y todo pero cuando presiono el boton de Iniciar sesion no hace nada
...........................................................................................................................................

```
<!--Inicio de sesion-->
        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">

                    <!-- Modal Header -->
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title text-warning">Inicio de Sesi&oacute;n</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Modal body -->
                    <div class="modal-body justify-content-center">
                        <div class="formulario">
                            <div class="contenedor">
                                <br>
                                <div class="inputWithIcon">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" placeholder="Correo electrónico" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </div>

                                <div class="inputWithIcon">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" placeholder="Contraseña" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <i class="fa fa-key fa-lg fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <asp:Button ID="LoginBoton" runat="server" Text="Ingresar" OnClick="LoginBoton_Click"/>
                            <p>Disfruta los nuevos servicios en linea de *******, revisa nuestras Condiciones de uso y Política.</p>
                            <p>¿No tienes una cuenta? <a class="link" href="registro.aspx">Registrate </a></p>
                            <br>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!--Aqui termina el modal-->
```

Y esto es lo que tengo en `aspx.cs` tengo solamente un `Redirect` porque estaba intentando con todo para ver si funcionaba

```
  protected void LoginBoton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("userlogged.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: Agrega el código que tienes para tratar de revisar lo que puede estar fallando...

Comment: si quiere que le ayude tiene que colocar el codigo fuente de su poblema, si algo presione f12 console

Comment: aun falta mas información como son los modal, con los botones n se hace nada

Comment: pues no entiendo para que si lo que no funciona son los botones uno despues del otro , el modal funciona perfectamente el problema que tengo es en los botones

Comment: tines jquery funcionando?

Comment: si todo funciona tal vez si despues de entregar los resultados recargo la tabla como seria eso?

Comment: Como comenta @marcosalbertosaavedrasanabr ¿Cómo es la modal? Hay algo que esta bloqueando el código o mal escrito. Por cierto, en el primer botón no pone onclick. Échale un ojo que no tengas eso en el código real.

Comment: @GDP  ya funciono asi sin mover le algo , no se que seria , pero muchas gracias

Comment: @JV93 Cosas que pasan, duendecillos :)